# XML view in browser breaks but shows in view source mode

Tags: xml

I have an xml that i want to parse into database. It breaks and therefore i cannot get all values into db. If i however right-click and view in source, the browser can then read it nicely. I then parse try to parse the parameter 
`view-source:www.example.com` to the script to read and parse into database. It fails. Is there a way I can effectively work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The browser can read it "nicely" in view source because it isn't trying to parse it as XML, so any errors in it are ignored.

You need to fix the XML.

Comment: Ok. So i need to fix the xml, right? In creating the xml, i think i might not have formatted it well or some characters breaking it. Is there a way to get it ignored whiles creating them?